# ImportError in python 3 for different file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

i want import a python file in to another directory, such as below:

```
a/
  __init__.py
  file1.py
  file2.py
b/
  __init__.py
  file3.py
  file4.py
```

I use from this code `form ..a.file1 import *` in file3.py. i get this error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I'm using VSCode, and debian linux. I read another posts in stachoverflow and use

```
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))
```

but my problem is not solved. help me pleas.

Comment: Try running your scripts from the folder where `a` and `b` are located (e.x. `python b/file3.py`) and just use `form a.file1 import *`.

Comment: Probably [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) you help and tryto follow instructions